# Can global variables be modified by a function without the use of adresses?

Tags: c, global

I have a program that has 3 global variables, 2 functions f() and g() and a main.

It looks like this:

```
int a, b, c;
int f(int x)
{
    return a * x;
}
int g()
{
    int c;
    c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    return c;
}
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    a = 2;
    b = 3;
    c = 4;
    x = f(a);
    y = g();
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", x, y, a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that in the g function since a c variable is declared then the c used inside of it is the new c and not the global variable.

But what I do not understand is why g() was able to modify the global variables.

Can't we only modify variables using pointers in these situations?

I don't really understand why a and b were swapped, my printf gives me: 4 2 3 2 4

Thanks

Comment: `Can't we only modify variables using pointers in these situations?` No.

Comment: I see, could you please tell me why the global variables are modified by g() ?

Comment: Because `g()` writes to them.

Comment: The variables a and b have a global scope and they are not overriden by any local variable (unlike c in g()).

Comment: I see thank you very much, I've never really used global variables so I was a bit startled when i saw that 2 variables were swapped without the use of pointers

Comment: Global variables should be used only when needed.

Comment: @stark: Everything should be used only when needed.

Comment: @Eric I will take your unneeded baklava.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables can be accessed directly, there is no need to use pointers.

As for why a and b were swapped, look at your `g` function:

```
    local_c = a // this is equal to 2;
    a = b // this is equal to 3;
    b = c // this is eqaul to 2, originally a;
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically every function can change the global variables without the use of pointers ? I see thanks

Comment: @FangYuan: No. Every function can access objects whose names it can see (as well as objects it has pointers for). If `x` is only declared after a function `foo`, then `foo` cannot access `x` by name. If `x` is only declared in a separately compiled source file, then `foo` cannot access `x` by name. If `x` is declared before `foo` in the same source file, and it is not hidden by declaring a different object with the name `x`, then `foo` can access `x` by name. (Note: Identifiers declared outside functions are properly called “external,” not “global.” C does not have true global names.)

Answer (score 1):

Global variables have a global scope, meaning they can be accessed and modified anywhere throughout the program.
And in this case there is no need to use pointer .

And to see why a and b where swapped you should check out your g function :

```
 c = a // now c = 2 ;
 a = b // now a = 3 ; a get the amount of b ; 
 b = c // now b = 2 ; now b get the first amount of a and it is clear a & b are exchanged ;
```